# Basis for euclidean topology

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B(x,r) \in R^n$ with euclidean metric and let be the following subsets of $R^n$

1. A={$B(x,r): x \in \mathbb{R^n}, r \in \mathbb{Q^+}$}
2. B={$B(x,r): x \in \mathbb{Q^n}, r \in \mathbb{Q^+}$}
3. C={$B(x,r): x \in \mathbb{R^n}, r \ge 1$}

I know that $\mathcal {B}$ is a basis for the topology if can I write every open set A in the topology as union of elements of the basis.
A basis for the euclidean topology is given from the $B(x,r)$ with $r \in \mathbb {R^+}, x \in \mathbb{R^n}$

If I consider the first case A my ideas is that every ball with real radius can be write as union of balls with rational radius because $\mathbb {Q}$ is a dense subset in $\mathbb{R}$.It's right? And for the other cases?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for radius $r \in \mathbb{R}, r > 0 $ , we can just take a sequence of rationals $q_n \in \mathbb{Q}_+ \cap (r-1/n, r)$ so that

\begin{align}
B(x, r) = \cup_{n}B(x, q_n)
\end{align}

B should can be shown if you choose center point $q \in \mathbb{Q}^n$
have coordinates $q_i \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (x_i-\epsilon, x_i+\epsilon)$ where

\begin{align}
0 < \sqrt{n\epsilon^2} <r/2
\end{align}

And C, look for a a ball of radius $r \geq 1$ that would fit in $B(0, 1/2)$ with center $0$.